# How to trim PATH enviroment variables

Tags: linux, zsh, path

When I see `$PATH` it seems like following .

`/bin:/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

`/bin` is duplicated in path, my question is how to drop duplicate these in path ?

Are there any good way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Before you try any of the solutions proposed, ensure to have a backup of your original PATH.

Comment: What shell do you use? The `zsh` shell can do this automatically.

Comment: Now that you've added the zsh tag -  the automatic method @Kusalananda mentioned is described here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24 ( look for `typeset -U path`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit overcomplicated, yet it should be able to work with any POSIX shell and also handle empty path entries:

```
trim_path(){
        PATH=${1%%:*}
        while :; do
                case $1 in
                *:*) set -- "${1#*:}" ;;
                *) break ;;
                esac
                case :$PATH: in
                *":${1%%:*}:"*) ;;
                *) PATH=$PATH:${1%%:*} ;;
                esac
        done
}

trim_path /bin:/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```